# Display Add to cart if Woocommerce Product Price is zero else display Add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a Woocommerce website with Astra theme. I am displaying Products with the help of shop module in Astra theme. Currently Astra shop module doesn't display the 'add to cart button'.
If I leave the price field blank, the add to cart, quantity field and price don't show up.
I will like the 'add to cart button' to show irrespective of the price.

Comment: It's a bit old but does [this help?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109477)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added the price to 0.00001, which will set the price to 0.00 and the 'add to cart button' will be added automatically. This is a good workaround for people who aren't good with code editing.

Answer (score 0):

To achive this you need to customize code inside your child theme. for shop page find the template file

```
wp-content/themes/astra/template-parts/woocommerce/archive-product.php
```

edit this file and add below code to check if the price of the product exists and then displays it with the 'price' class.

```
if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) {
    echo '<span class="price">' . $price_html . '</span>';
}
```

add below hook to insert add to cart button in theme's function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

After this "Add to cart" will be displayed on the shop page regardless of either the price is filled in or not.

Comment: And if you don't have a child theme what can you do?

Comment: If you don't have child theme then put this code directly inside main theme.